# What is the best apache configuration for me?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mysql, configuration

I started to a new job. And my mission on servers which is not my work :(

We have around 200 websites which use php - mysql.

netstat -an|grep -c :80 is around 500

24GB ram with 2 E5420 Cpu

Load average is around 15

its too much?

Can you help me to configure it?

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Is something not working? By itself a load average of 15 isn't a problem, as long as the machine & sites are responsive...

Answer (score 1):

Load Average doesn't equate to a % of cpu usage.

It's a metric referring to (this is a gross simplification) how much of your processing power is being requested. And which is displayed in 1 minute, 5 minute, and 15 minute intervals.

In your case, you have 2 quad core CPUs without hyperthreading and therefore 8 cores total. Which means that a load average equivalent to 100% cpu use would be 8.

The fact your load average is at 15 means that you have need of more processing time than you have processor cores, so your applications end up having to wait. Ideally, you'd not want your load averages to go above 8 for best response times.

Answer (score -2):

15% CPU is just fine.  So is 500 connections at a time.

Comment: Load average isn't cpu usage.